# How to handle custom url schemes in swift (XCode 8)?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I tried using this function to receive the parameters from the custom url:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```

However, the function is never called and I receive warning: "Instance method 'application(*:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)' nearly matches optional argument 'application(*:open:sourceApplication:annotation:)' of protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate.

Based on [XCode 8 Warning "Instance method nearly matches optional requirement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495773/xcode-8-warning-instance-method-nearly-matches-optional-requirement) I tried using @objc with no success. How can I build a function that will be called when the app is opened and give me the parameters from the custom url scheme?

Comment: why dont you upvote the accepted answer? this user took his time to help you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation for `UIApplicationDelegate`. Under Swift 3 the delegate method is:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```

Not

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```

But that one is deprecated anyway. You should be using (with iOS 9.0 and later):

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```