# UIApplication.sharedApplication.open() doesn't load url

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm working with `Swift 3 and Xcode 8 (iOS 10.1)`, I'm completely new to the whole world. :)

I'm authenticating against an external app to get an access token. The use case is:

1) Load external app from my app

2) Validate the user and get the access token

3) Redirect back to my app from external app

I am able to do 1) and 2), but not 3). The external app has specified that you configure a redirect parameter, and I've done that. But alas, no cigar.

I have set up URL schemes in `Info.plist` for both apps. I don't get any errors in the console or debugger.

I have been googling and researching for the past 4 days and this is the solution I have come up with so far. Right now, I see the console messages, but the external app is no longer opening up.

**AppDelegate**

```
  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if (url.scheme == "extapp") {
        print("working with extapp scheme")
    } else if (url.scheme == "myapp") {
        print("redirecting back to app after working with extapp")
    }
    return true
  }
```

**ViewController**

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let id = text.text
    let currentCharacterCount = id.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    if currentCharacterCount == 0 {
        self.showAlert(text: "Please provide a id.")
    } else if currentCharacterCount < 10 {
        self.showAlert(text: "Oh! id doesn't seem to be in the correct format. Try again.")
    } else {
        if (self.firebaseData.callAuth(loggedIn: id!)) {
            OpenExtApp()
        }
    }
}

func OpenExtApp() {
    let Url = URL(string: "extapp:///?autostart=\(token)&redirect=myapp://key")
    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(Url!)) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(Url!, options: [:])
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate your help in any way.

Comment: are you added the url schema  `extapp` in your plist

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes, I have, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Is it goes inside if block?, put break point and check once.

Comment: @NiravD you mean, in the AppDelegate code or ViewController?

Comment: In the `OpenExtApp` method's if block

Comment: Yes, it does. Is there a way to see what error/success is returned from the open method? I couldn't find anything online about this.

Comment: You can use completion block of open method for that.

Comment: try to type myapp://key in safari browser to ensure your app can be opened from the url schema. If it is ok, Probably the error is in ext app part. Maybe need to encode your myapp://key url so that external app can read it correctly.

Comment: @Surely I can open the app from Safari. I will try encoding. Which option do I use in `addingPercentEncoding`? I have tried it before with .urlAllowHost, but it didn't help/work.

Comment: Please make sure are you using link with the -  http://

Comment: @Anand that didn't work, it opened up Safari rather than the extapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to have been with the `addingPercentEncoding`method I was using to encode the `redirect` parameter. I didn't notice that the parameter wasn't being encoded properly. It turns out that the default filter in with `AllowedCharacters` doesn't encode / and :. It's a known issue with Apple. This solved the encoding problem and, in turn, the problem I was having with opening the extapp:

```
let characterSetTobeAllowed = (CharacterSet(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] ").inverted)
let redirect = parameter.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: characterSetTobeAllowed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out and also make sure to add the custom schemes to your info.plist file
[How to handle custom url schemes in swift (XCode 8)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075122/how-to-handle-custom-url-schemes-in-swift-xcode-8)

Comment: thanks for your answer, Ahmed. My method signature in AppDelegate is as what is specified in the link you provided.