# Error when trying to get user location (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get user's location on iOS.
I use `CLLocationManagerDelegate` for it.

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.requestLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.first
    print("locations = \(location?.coordinate.latitude) \(location?.coordinate.longitude)")
}
```

But I get this error

> 2017-03-24 18:03:57.183 *** Assertion failure in -[CLLocationManager requestLocation],
>        /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreLocationFramework_Sim/CoreLocation-2100.0.34/Framework/CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.m:867
>       2017-03-24 18:03:57.194 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>        reason: 'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError:'

After implementing `locationManager:didFailWithError:`

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error.description)
}
```

I have this warning

> Instance method 'locationManager(*:didFailWithError:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'locationManager(*:didFailWithError:)' 
>        of protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'

And again this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>        reason: 'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError:'

I dont know what incorrect. `locationManager:didFailWithError:` implemented, but I have same error.

Comment: here they say its a bug in 8.1 xcode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495773/xcode-8-warning-instance-method-nearly-matches-optional-requirement what is your xcode version. maybe you need to update.

Comment: What's your definition for locationManager?

Comment: @hasan83 i have xcode 8.2.1

Comment: @C6Silver   let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

Comment: Is the containing class inheriting from NSObject? I was able to get this to build without warnings after inheriting from NSObject.

Comment: @faircloud No, this class isnt inheriting from NSObject

Answer (score 0):

changing to

```
@objc(locationManager:didFailWithError:)
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

helped in my situation

Comment: so no crash now?

Comment: @hasan83 yes, no crash, but i still have this warning