# Instance method 'xyz()' nearly matches optional requirement 'xyz()' of protocol 'ABDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates, xcode9.2

cannot override delegate functions,

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and other functions related to app delegates are fine but when i tried to use `application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` got the warning below and even after running an app it's not invoked.

[image: Instance method nearly matches optional requirements]

Also getting the same warning on SafariVC Delegate
[image]

Comment: Have your tried cleaning the project and deleting derived data?

Comment: @Malik : multiple times...

Comment: It's `ObjC->Swift` name translation bug. Check answers for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495773/xcode-8-warning-instance-method-nearly-matches-optional-requirement

Answer (score 0):

MY BAD !!

Actually the main problem with my code is CLASS NAME, i created a class having name URL and as you know NSURL is now URL.
Whenever i override any delegates functions having URL in it's parameters Xcode gives me the warning because it gets my URL class not from SDK.
So you can say the classes names are also reserved and shouldn't be used.