# timeout if request processing not finished within specified time

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using tomcat 6. Say i send a request to web server which takes more than 20 seconds. Is there any default timeout in tomcat when it will stop processing that request if response
is not sent back within n seconds ? If yes what's the property name in server/context.xml ?

I found  `connectionTimeout` but it determines how long Tomcat will wait for the http request line once a connection is established. It doesn't tell how long the server waits for the request to finish processing

Answer (score 0):

You can only accompiish this by setting client-side read timeouts. Tomcat doesn't have request processing timeouts, only connection and read timeouts.

Comment: is n't  tomcat read timeout is the property where it tells how long the server waits for the request to finish processing ?

Comment: I believe you are talking about `so timeout`  which to me looks same which I asked for i.e  the client socket waits for response after sending the request(as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184899/what-is-the-difference-between-the-setconnectiontimeout-setsotimeout-and-http) But it seems to be applicable for onli NIO implementation not for standard implementation ?

Comment: any thoughts  on my comments?