# Why do I get java.net.SocketTimeoutException with OkHttp?

Tags: java, http, okhttp

Here's my configuration:

```
httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .callTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
        .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
        .writeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
        .build();
```

I have a multithreaded process that uses this client. **Few seconds** after running I'm getting:

> **java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout**
>   at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:232)
>   at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:286)
>   at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
>   at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:358)

How is it possible if I configured the timeouts to 60 seconds?

**EDIT:**
Even adding a custom dispatcher didn't help:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
dispatcher.setMaxRequests(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

**TECHNICAL DETAILS:**
As opposed to what I've said, I'm running both the client and the server on Linux machines:

> Client's machine: net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
>   Server's machine: net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608499/getting-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-connection-timed-out-in-android)

Comment: @MichielLeegwater, it's not duplicate and anyhow the linked SO post doesn't offer a reasonable solution

Comment: have you considered the possibility that the server has a very small timeout and that it has nothing to do with your code ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184899/what-is-the-difference-between-the-setconnectiontimeout-setsotimeout-and-http
you may want to see this

Comment: @a_local_nobody, I actually have considered this option but I thought (maybe falsely) that timeout exception can happen only from client side. I'm using a vanilla Flask server so that might be it - If you want to collect the bounty please write it as an answer

Comment: no, you're establishing a session between yourself and the server, so it's entirely possible the server kicks you out

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I think that I imagined that there's another unique exception for server's timeout (something like Connection Refused or whatever)

Comment: The difference is that you'd get an http response 408, otherwise all the client could say is "connection closed". Might be worth logging or sniffing packets to check whether it's that

Comment: Because you set a 60s read timeout and it expired. The peer didn't respond within 60 seconds. Either your timeout is too short (unlikely with this value) or there is something wrong wth the server,

Comment: @user207421, it can't be client side as I explained - since the application ran for only few seconds

Comment: Are you on Linux, iOS, Android or Windows? Did you change the default system settings for the network? And what exactly is "few seconds"?

Comment: client - MacOS, Server - Flask on Ubuntu. Few seconds is literally few seconds (let's say 5)

Comment: Show the output of `sysctl net.inet.tcp` on Mac, I'm assuming that's where your code is getting a timeout exception. If not please clarify what's the server doing (Isn't Flask a Python thing?).

Comment: Do you know from logs as to how much time is this timeout? Like 30 sec or even lesser? Also which server does this client connects to?

Comment: @yaseco, please add more code related to how your thread makes call

Comment: This is fixed in okhttps 4.3. See https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3146#issuecomment-569986444

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely affected by the socket timeouts imposed by the operating system. Java can't extend them since the sockets are managed by the system. As per [this great answer, "Changing TCP Timeouts" section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33927447/1602555):

> Unfortunately since TCP connections are managed on the OS level, Java does not support configuring timeouts on a per-socket level such as in `java.net.Socket`. I have found some attempts to use Java Native Interface (JNI) to create Java sockets that call native code to configure these options, but none appear to have widespread community adoption or support.

For MacOS you have to look at `sysctl net.inet.tcp` output and see what are the system limits.

Comment: Thanks Karol (I guess that same command applies for Linux, right?)

Comment: So to sum up, defining timeouts on application-level (in Java) is meaningless as the socket timeouts are defined on the OS level.

Comment: On my linux machine I see: net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200

Comment: You can decrease the timeout limit in Java but you can't increase it past the OS timeout limit. At this point I don't understand if you are getting this timeout on MacOS or Linux, the limits are OS dependent. Rewrite your question to clearly specify the OS and code that causes the problem, right now it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is somewhere else. The timeout does work. I tried the following on my machine and it worked for 30 seconds

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

/**
 *
 * @author jingged
 */
public class Test {
OkHttpClient httpClient = null;
     void initClient(){
        httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.initClient();
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://10.255.255.1").build();
                   Instant start = Instant.now();
                   try (Response response = test.httpClient.newCall(request).execute()) {
                        String s =  response.body().string();
                        System.out.println(s);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        if (ex instanceof java.net.SocketTimeoutException){
                            System.err.print("Socket TimeOut");
                        }else{
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                   Instant end = Instant.now();
                    Duration interval = Duration.between(start, end);
                    System.out.println("Execution time " + interval.getSeconds()+" seconds");
                }

            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Execution time 30 seconds
Execution time 30 seconds
Execution time 30 seconds
Execution time 30 seconds
Execution time 30 seconds
Execution time 30 seconds
Execution time 30 seconds
Execution time 30 seconds
Execution time 30 seconds
Execution time 30 seconds
Socket TimeOutSocket TimeOutSocket TimeOutSocket TimeOutSocket TimeOutSocket TimeOutSocket TimeOutSocket TimeOutSocket TimeOutSocket TimeOut
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 32 seconds)
```

Try the above code. the url mentioned in the above code will produce TimeOut exception as it doesn't exists but the timeout time should keep it going for 30 seconds.
BTW I tested this on MAC OS High Sierra with Java 8 and netbeans 8.2 with okhttp3