# SocketTimeoutException With OkHttp on Kotlin on PDA3505

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp, socket-timeout-exception

I'm using this Chinese device PDA3505 which is android 6.0 and have written a kotlin application for it. To print something (it has a thermal printer) it needs to fetch print data from the server, which in hindsight works normally on Wi-Fi but when I switched over to the local mobile internet it started giving me SocketTimeoutExceptions. (and it has to be on the local mobile internet)

The code used to create OkHttpClient:

```
private var httpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .callTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pingInterval(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
```

(Increasing the 30seconds and 15seconds doesn't change the behaviour)

The code used to call the API:

```
        val url = apiUrl + urlPath

        val request: Request = if (!withHeaders) {
            Request
                .Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(postBody)
                .build()
        } else {
            Request
                .Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(postBody)
                .addHeader("Authorization", getAuthToken())
                .build()
        }

        try {
            val response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()

            if (response != null) {
                return if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val reqBody: String? = response.body?.string()
                    if (reqBody != null && reqBody != "" && reqBody != "null") {
                        JSONObject(reqBody)
                    } else {
                        null
                    }
                } else {
                    null
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: SocketTimeoutException) {
            println(ex)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e)
        }

        return null
```

it takes a long time to process, and yes the local mobile internet in this device is slow. (it doesn't have 4G and its the only option I have). The best I found here was here -> [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412716/why-do-i-get-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-with-okhttp?fbclid=IwAR2_z5n6paVgxf7sgNI3UklLmxe2YZDmjAx25RBKthyxUFp72GsT3wRY86M), but I can't make anything of it or if its possible to extend tcp_socket connection time.
As for the API server, I have tested it and the maximum response time is 0.3s (most traffic on this API would be 10 user/hour) so I'm thinking the API isn't at fault.

Is there anyway to confirm that sockets have a certain time? and can I extend that time? or is the problem something else and I'm not seeing it? help pls

I Tried to extend the OkHttpClient timeouts but to no avail. It works on Wi-Fi but fails and gives SocketTimeoutException on local Mobile internet which is 3G (that's the maximum this device can connect to)